# can doctrine generate model classes with prefix?

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine

I am have modular structure in my project

```
--application
----modules
-----admin
------models
-----client
------models
```

Now when I generate the models and database using doctrine ( ./doctrine build-all-reload
).
it genrate the classes

```
class Car extends BaseCar
{ }

abstract class BaseCar extends Doctrine_Record
{ // code removed }
```

for zend to pick up these classess
I have to rename them like this

```
class admin_Model_Car extends admin_Model_generated_BaseCar
{ }

abstract class admin_Model_generated_BaseCar extends Doctrine_Record
{ // code removed }
```

Is there a way that I can genate the classes with prefix MODULENAME_MODEL_CLASSNAME?

So I don't need to change it.

Comment: I tried this one but did not work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/934394/can-doctrine-generated-models-have-a-prefix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these lines in application.ini file / module.ini file.

```
doctrine.generate_models_options.pearStyle = true
doctrine.generate_models_options.generateTableClasses = false
doctrine.generate_models_options.generateBaseClasses = true
doctrine.generate_models_options.baseClassPrefix = "Base_"
doctrine.generate_models_options.baseClassesDirectory =
doctrine.generate_models_options.classPrefixFiles = false
doctrine.generate_models_options.classPrefix = "admin_Model_"
```